# Sphinx filter without search

Tags: sphinx

I need to get  filtered data , without some search keyword.
Basically imagine query like this

```
select  ras.resource_id
from    resource_account_share ras, resource_account_share_contract rasc,
                                contract cnt
where   ras.id=rasc.share_id and rasc.contract_id=cnt.id and
                                (cnt.assignor_id='28' or cnt.assignee_id='28')))
```

In my sphinx.conf i set attributes to assignor_id and assignee_id , and then i filter inserting assignee id and assignor id , but api requires to insert a query string , which i dont need. I don't even have fields to search for string and i don't need it/. All i need is filtered data by assignee_id or assignor_id .

So how do i get this data?

---

**EDIT** found on http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/

***How do I filter, sort, or group by string column without string attributes?***

You can do all of this, except for precise arbtrary-length sorting over several indexes.

To filter and group, you can replace the string with an unique numeric ID. Sometimes its possible to create a lookup dictionary in the database (eg. for fixed lists of cities or countries), or even use an existing one, replace strings with their IDs in that dictionary, then filter and group on that ID. If not, you can always replace the string with its checksum, eg. CRC32() or (any) 64 bits taken from MD5() at indexing time (no need to alter the tables!), store it using sql_attr_uint or sql_attr_bigint respectively, and then filter or group on that checksum attribute. (Note that there's a certain chance of CRC32() collisions if you have millions of strings but practically zero chance of MD5() collisions.)

Sorting is harder, but also possible to some extent. First, you can use sql_attr_str2ordinal that replaces every string with its ordinal number (a sequential number in the sorted list of all the uniqie strings mentioned in this index). However, that will produce garbled results when querying through several indexes at a time, because every index will assign its own sequential number to the same strings. Ie. string "zzz" could be number 1000 in index A but at the same time number 1 in index B, and errorneously float to the top when searching through both A+B. Second, you can extract 4-byte or 8-byte substrings, store them as attributes, and sort on those attributes. That will work across different indexes, but sort only on few first bytes.

But don't really understand how to do it.

---

**EDIT #2**

Okay.. Basically it is lots of tables with one huge sql query , but i'll take little part of it and make it as simple as possible , which shows my problem because everything else is basically the same.. So ...

**Tables**

Recording table

```
CREATE TABLE `recording` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4888 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Resource_account_share

```
CREATE TABLE `resource_account_share` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resource_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Mysql query**

```
select  cmp.id, cmp.title_en as `title`,
                    date_format(cmp.released_date, '%d.%m.%Y') released_date,
                    cmp.ean, cmp.isrc, cmp.performers
            from    recording cmp
            where 1=1
            and (cmp.id in (select resource_id from resource_account_share where account_id='?')
```

? - is account id , which is inserted when search is submited.

I am pretty sure what i am trying to do is made with setSelect, but as i don't understand how it works , my plan was ....

1) To index recording table

2) To index resource_account_share table

3) Then i sphinx.conf set 2 sources : source recording and source resource_account_share

```
source recording
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = user
    sql_pass        = password
    sql_db          = db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        select  cmp.id, cmp.title_en as `title`,\
                    date_format(cmp.released_date, '%d.%m.%Y') released_date,\
                    cmp.ean, cmp.isrc, cmp.performers\
            from    recording cmp

    sql_attr_uint       = id
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM recording WHERE id=$id
}

source resource_account_share
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = user
    sql_pass        = password
    sql_db          = db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        select resource_id from resource_account_share

    sql_attr_uint       = account_id
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM recording WHERE id=$id
}
```

4) Then in php file filter resource_account_share by account_id  (`$cl->SetFilter('account_id',array('28'));`)

5) Get data from resource_account_share index and insert this data in to recroding table filter

```
$cl->SetFilter('id',array(data_fetched_from_resource_account_share));
```

Here maybe mistakes because a wrote it on the fly , just cutting some real queries in half , but you get the idea..... My problem is that i don't know how to link those tables with sphinx , that's why i wanted to just filter resource_account_share table first, but got stuck on the problem , that i can't just filter , i need to search for some keyword too , which i don't need here...

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/matching-modes.html

> SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN, matches query, forcibly using the "full scan" mode as below. NB, any query terms will be ignored, such that filters, filter-ranges and grouping will still be applied, but no text-matching.

you should use

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert an empty query string , like $sphinx->Query('','indexname')

Comment: I tried ... and i got nothing....  What i found though is in the update of the question , but i don't really get how to do it

Comment: @Viktor : that's an old way to filter/sort/group strings, but it's pretty deprecated , since there are new attributes that can handle all that. Better post your conf and the code you try to execute.

Comment: Watch second edit.... I wrote what i want to do .... I  hope you can help me ... Because i got stuck on it pretty badly , and have no idea how to solve this problem.